# Angular app ng build --prod fails with ERROR in scripts.6e3f538f18f55b02ca8a.js from Terser

Tags: angular, firebase, angular9

Angular version 9.1.4 and cli 9.1.8

I am trying to get a production build of my angular app and getting the following error. I don't recall to have updated anything since my last successfull prod build

All my previous ng build --prod worked fine however currently getting this error

```
ERROR in scripts.6e3f538f18f55b02ca8a.js from Terser
Unexpected character '@' [scripts.6e3f538f18f55b02ca8a.js:15301,0]
    at Q (/Users/<appfolder>/node_modules/terser/dist/bundle.min.js:1:19349)
    at m (/Users/<appfolder>/node_modules/terser/dist/bundle.min.js:1:20662)
    at Object.K [as input] (/Users/<appfolder>/hello-world/node_modules/terser/dist/bundle.min.js:1:26168)
    at a (/Users/<appfolder>/node_modules/terser/dist/bundle.min.js:1:27583)
    at s (/Users/<appfolder>/node_modules/terser/dist/bundle.min.js:1:27637)
    at /Users/<appfolder>/node_modules/terser/dist/bundle.min.js:1:30242
    at /Users/<appfolder>/node_modules/terser/dist/bundle.min.js:1:28555
    at /Users/<appfolder>/node_modules/terser/dist/bundle.min.js:1:50771
    at ue (/Users/<appfolder>/node_modules/terser/dist/bundle.min.js:1:50908)
    at Eo (/Users/<appfolder>/node_modules/terser/dist/bundle.min.js:1:336804)
```

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Did you open that file to check when the code looks like at this line?

Comment: I don't see file "scripts.6e3f538f18f55b02ca8a.js" under /terser/dist/.

Comment: for     at Q (/Users/<appfolder>/node_modules/terser/dist/bundle.min.js:1:19349)
 on the second line error I see this function Y(e) { return e >= 48 && e <= 57 }

Comment: most probably this is due to invalid character in your one of css or sacss files. can you search css files with @ mark and reply ?

Comment: I am using styles.css with bootstrap and font-awesome css styles and below is the only @ matches in style.css `@import "~bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";
@import "~font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css";`

Comment: Just wondering if this could be a memory issue mentioned in this thread ? https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/5618

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue got resolved for me

Added this line into the package.json file, under the scripts key:
```
"ng-high-memory": "node --max_old_space_size=8000 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng",

```
The link below helped me
https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/5618
```